# Using Raspberry Pi as Wireless Access Point means I cannot SSH to it

Tags: networking, ssh, wireless, ethernet, static-ip

So I have set up my raspberry pi as a wireless access point using HostAPD and Bridge.

I have bridged my wlan0 to eth0. And I can connect to my Access Point successfully. But I also have a webserver on that Pi. And with the access point software I cannot seem to be able to connect to my pi via SSH over ethernet. Like I usually would.

I have scanned my network and my raspberry pi does not show up anymore, so I cant SSH to it or use It as a WebServer

It there any way I can allow this or is this a direct limitation of using the Pi as a WAP Bridge?

Thank you

Comment: When you connect via Wifi, can you if see sshd is running and on what IP address it is listening?

Answer (score 4):

Try assigning an IP address to the bridge interface (e.g. `br0`),

Answer (score 3):

adding an IP to br0 solved this problem for me. thanks.

- raspbian 10.3: /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
  address 10.0.0.10
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: thank you for the advice, the easiest fix I've seen. IP addresses of course have to comply with your routers network its not 10.0... for all