# Wifi access point loses internet when ethernet plugged in

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-4

I'm aware there are related questions to this problem but none of them have solved my issue so far.

I'm trying to set up a wifi access point with my pi 4B. I'm following this guide exactly: https://raspberrypi-guide.github.io/networking/create-wireless-access-point (I've also tried the updated version of enabling hostapd, without unmasking the service).

I have the bridge set up and working. I have also assigned it a static ip along with wlan0. When the ethernet cable is plugged in though, neither ip's come up as being up on the network. When I take out the ethernet cable, wlan0's ip is up and I can ssh into it like normal. At no point does the ssid for the access point appear on my phone. I've tried setting a static ip to eth0 as well but there's no change in behavior.

Here are all the related questions I've tried for solutions to show what I've already tried:

[Connection on Raspberry/Ubuntu as Access Point Wifi > Ethernet > Internet not going through](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135757/connection-on-raspberry-ubuntu-as-access-point-wifi-ethernet-internet-not-go)

[Strange wifi/ethernet behaviour when plugging in/out ethernet cable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23448/strange-wifi-ethernet-behaviour-when-plugging-in-out-ethernet-cable)

[Ethernet Blocks Internet of Wifi Access Point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79631/ethernet-blocks-internet-of-wifi-access-point)

[Using Raspberry Pi as Wireless Access Point means I cannot SSH to it](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79059/using-raspberry-pi-as-wireless-access-point-means-i-cannot-ssh-to-it)

EDIT:

I just found a typo in my hostapd.conf which was stopping hostapd from launching. Now the access point successfully starts up and I can connect to it. However, neither of the static IPs I assigned show up on the network, and I don't see any new IP that may have been assigned to eth0, so I still can't access the pi. Worse, before if I unplugged eth0, wlan0's IP would appear. Now this is no longer the case.

EDIT 2:

Adding info about my network from the comments and my configuration files:

I have a home router which the pi is plugged into via eth0, as well as connected to via wlan0. Here is my dhcpcd.conf describing the static IPs given to interfaces:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.2/24
static router=192.168.1.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.254
nohook wpa_supplicant

interface br0
static ip_address=192.168.1.3/24
static router=192.168.1.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.254
```

I have a desktop connected to ethernet on the same network which I've been trying to connect to the pi through, but no addresses (the static ones or otherwise) come up as connected devices on the network via nmap.

For clarification like to be able to connect to the pi via ssh and other services through eth0, and bridge wifi connections from devices like my laptop or my phone from wlan0 to eth0 in order to boost my network's wifi range.

Here is my hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
channel=7
country_code=GB
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ssid=<SSID>
wpa_passphrase=<PASSWD>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Show the configuration files you modified, the commands you ran with their output, how you checked the result ... Add links to the related questions that did not help, so that we know what you already tried.

Comment: All the configuration and changes I've done are in the provided link. I could copy paste each step into the question but that feels a little redundant. I'll edit in the related questions now though sure.

Comment: So you used all commands and file changes exactly as in the referenced guide (except passwords) and nothing else? Please add details about your network and IP addresses of all devices involved. My interpretation of "When I take out the ethernet cable, wlan0's ip is up and I can ssh into it like normal." is that `wlan0` is connected to some access point instead of providing one. Is this correct? Do you want to use the same interface to connect to your existing AP and providing an AP? Is the ethernet cable connected to your router? Did you use the wired network before trying to set up the AP?

Comment: Yes, it's all exactly as the guide. wlan0 has address 192.168.1.2, br0 has 192.168.1.3 and I'm not sure what eth0 looks like when plugged in as obviously I can't connect but it has no entry in /etc/dhcpcd.conf other than denyinterface eth0. When eth0 is unplugged, I can connect to wlan0 on .1.2. I'd like to connect to the pi through eth0 and have wlan0 bridge connections to eth0. eth0 is connected to the router yes, and I could connect to it through eth0 before adding br0.

Comment: @Bodo I've just made an important edit you should make sure to read, thanks.

Comment: add your configuration info to the question if you want help with your confiugration

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. Please describe or draw your network and and show the addresses of all devices (computers, router, phone, ...) and explain what you want to achieve. Why do you need a network bridge?

Comment: @JaromandaX, Bodo - Done